# Opening link in new tab from Blazor Server

Tags: javascript, ios, blazor-server-side, mobile-safari

I'm trying to open a link in a new tab from a Blazor Server application. I tried several methods such as

```
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("open", action.ActionData, "_blank");
```

as well as

```
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("NavigateTo", action.ActionData);
```

whereas the NavigateTo function appears as follows:

```
window.NavigateTo = (url) => {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.target = '_blank';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.remove();
}
```

Everything is working fine in all browsers except for Safari on IOS.

Has anybody found a solution to this problem? As I found out, there is a problem opening a new tab in Safari from an asynchronous task. But I couldn't find a way to start this synchronously from Blazor Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quite simple answer to my problem. As the tab stays open, I could just execute the action in a onclick event and add a href attribute to the link with the target="_blank" attribute.

```
<a @onclick="ExecuteBackgroundTask" href="https://link.to.newpage" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    Click there to open link in new tab and execute some work in the background.
</a>
```

The browser will open the link in a new tab and execute the action in the background in the old tab.

Answer (score 0):

This is a deliberate feature by the browser, blocking you from doing something obnoxious with your code.  People definitely don't WANT a site they visit to just start spawning new pages whenever it wants to.  You might spawn one page, or you might spawn a dozen popup ads.

The minimum requirement for almost any mobile media is that it is initialized in a legitimate UI interaction-- say, the actual (not simulated) click of a button on the client screen.

Most of my sites have an "ENTER SITE" button and nothing else on the front page.  I use this to preload audio, request media recorder permissions, etc.  It's a hack and a bit of a dirty trick, but it allows me to sync audio with images in slideshows and so on.

So I suggest you do as much of the link initialization as you can in a click handler in javascript, rather than in Blazor interop calls.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am using this code in a Learn Management System (LMS). The user is clicking on a button, and then this click has to be registered in the database. As soon as the saving process is completed, the link should be opened in a new tab, so that he user can simply close the new tab and return to the LMS system. Do you have a good ideo how I could change the link initialization process?

Comment: I don't have an Apple device, but let me ask you this: If you simply call your navigate routine from a button.click() handler in JavaScript, i.e. forgetting about anything in Blazor for now, can you open a new tab at all?  If Safari prevents new tabs by default, then there will be nothing you can do about this, and you'll have to use some kind of modal popup in Blazor rather than opening a new tab.